# Custom Excel template shows properties dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, templates

I followed the very handy guide here: [Changing the default Excel template](http://computertrainer.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/change-default-new-workbook-in-excel/) to change the default template for Excel so that when I launch Excel it's set up with my custom colours and layouts.

It worked perfectly but when I open Excel I get the dropdown shown here:
[image: Properties]

It wants properties for data connections (of which there aren't any) and doc properties. I can just press the X to close it but I know that my team will complain about it being a hinderance and we need to get the default template into regular use.

What causes this, and is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the document information panel (DIP) with the server properties. I have only seen such a DIP for files that are stored in SharePoint and document metadata (properties) can be set through the DIP.

This looks a bit different though, but still points to a server location as opposed to a document stored on a mapped drive.

You can click the drop-down next to the word "Server" and select the regular Excel DIP instead.

With the SharePoint DIP there is a setting to toggle whether the DIP is automatically opened with the file. Try and see if you can find a similar setting for your server specific DIP and toggle it off.

Comment: Thanks teylyn, I couldn't find an option for this but I scrapped the templates and rebuilt them from a new doc rather than one that had had all other content deleted (encluding a database link) and then built over. Worked perfectly.